# Choose coordinate system of grid overlay with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, astropy

How can I tell which coordinate system is being used in a plot, and how do I specify which coordinate system I want to be used for the overlaying grid ?

```
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
hdu = fits.open(image_file)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

plt.subplot(projection=wcs) 
plt.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower') 
plt.grid(color='white', ls='solid')
plt.show()
```

How would I specify that I want galactic (or equatorial) coordinates to be used for the `plt.grid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
hdu = fits.open(image_file)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
plt.subplot(projection=wcs) 
plt.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower') 
ax = fig.gca()
overlay = ax.get_coords_overlay('galactic')
overlay.grid(color='red', ls='dotted')
plt.show()
```

As it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116787/how-to-plot-gaia-astrometry-data-to-tess-images-using-python). (Did not check the math behind it.)